# Using the Bubble Sort Algorithm on Windows Form C# to sort random numbers?

Tags: c#, random, windows-forms-designer, bubble-sort

I am suppose to be writing a C# program in visual studios windows forms application that needs to implement the following functionalities:

Create 1,000 random numbers between 1 and 5000

Use the bubble sort algorithm and sort the 1000 numbers

This is the code that I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Prog7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random num = new Random();
        string line = Environment.NewLine;
        int nbr = num.Next(0, 5001);
        textNumbers.Text = nbr.ToString();

        for(int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            nbr = num.Next(0, 5001);
            textNumbers.Text = textNumbers.Text + line + nbr.ToString();
        }

    }

    private void SortBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool inorder = false;
        while (!inorder)
        {
            inorder = true;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
            {
                if (swap(ref i, ref i + 1))
                    inorder = false;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            nbr = num.Next(0, 5001);
            SortBox.Text = SortBox.Text + line + nbr.ToString();
        }


    }

    private bool swap(ref int top, ref int bottom)
    {
        int temp;

        if (top <= bottom)
            return false;

        temp = top;
        top = bottom;
        bottom = temp;
        return true;

    }
}
}
```

My original plan was to have the form have a button for generating the numbers and a button for sorting the numbers with two textboxes to list down the numbers.The code in my btnGenerate_Click works fine for generating the 1000 different numbers. But I am having a difficulty figuring out how I can input the bubble sort algorithm into this program. I looked up many examples online on what to do but many of the examples involve a array list which im not using. The program I have right now for SortBtn_Click obviously doesnt work. If anyone can give me suggestion on how to make it work or a easier way to create this program please let me know! I appreciate all the help anyone is willing to provide.

Comment: Do you want to sort numbers present in `textNumbers` textbox? If Yes, then you are not using those numbers as input to bubble sort. If No then please let me know use of click event of `btnGenerate`

Comment: yes I want to use the numbers that are generated in the textnumbers textbox and sort them so they can display in the SortBox. Can you show me how to exactly so that with bubblesort because anything I really put down I get some form of error?

Comment: You should note that inside the `btnGenerate_Click` event… you are “creating” the variables “num, “line” and “nbr”. Since they will go out of scope when the code leaves the `btnGenerate_Click` event, you won’t be able to use those variables as you are in the other method `SortBtn_Clicks`.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps to fix your issue:

1. Instead of creating new random number in `SortBtn_Click` function, use text present in `textNumber` textbox.
2. In `SortBtn_Click` function, First check `textNumber` is null or empty. If the string is null or empty, then throw an error.
3. In else part, split string and convert it into integer array.

*you can split string using following code.*

```
 string[] strArr = textNumber.Text.split(Environment.NewLine);
```

*Now convert string array into integer array.*

```
int[] intArr = Array.ConvertAll(strArr, Int32.Parse);
```

Now apply bubble sort on intArr variable, store result in `SortBox.Text` text field

**Note: As @JohnG mentioned about variables used in `btnGenerate_Click` (num, line, nbr) goes out of scope when execution leaves `btnGenerate_click` function. So you can not use those variables into other function. If you want to use those variables then declare that variables in class scope([Global declaration](https://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variable))**